# Faceing issue with second query which is depend on first query

Tags: mysql, jdbc, connection

In my below code ist query is successfully done but from ist query result need to use for 2nd query its not working

```
        try{

            pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM loanrequest where loan_status_id='1' and loan_sub_status_id is NULL and business_id!=0 and white_label_id=1 order by loanId desc limit 1;;");


            ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();



            while(rs.next()){  //next result will check until the result 

                String dbbusinessname=rs.getString("loan_ref_id");
                xls.setCellData("Data","loan_ref_id",35,dbbusinessname);
                System.out.println(dbbusinessname);

                String dbloanId=rs.getString("loanId");
                xls.setCellData("Data","loanId",35,dbloanId);


                //Need to use loan id in my 2nd query
```

// this part is depend on ist query .
//this below query its not working

```
                pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM loan_bank_mapping where loan_id='dbloanId';;");

                ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();



            while(rs.next()){  //next result will check until the result 

                String dbloan_bank_mapping_id=rs.getString("loan_bank_mapping_id");
                xls.setCellData("Data","loan_bank_mapping_id",35,dbloan_bank_mapping_id);
                System.out.println(dbbusinessname);




            }
            }catch (Exception e) {


                System.out.println("Error in fireing query");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail("Exception in query"+e.getMessage());

                //throw new SkipException("Could not establish connection");
            }//Create the object of driver class
```

public void disconnect(){

```
    //when doing testing after testing  need to close orelse trouble will come


    try {


        if(rs!=null){
            rs.close();
        }


        if(pstmt!=null){
            pstmt.close();
        }

        if((conn!=null) && (!conn.isClosed())){
            conn.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: To help us debug your problem can you show us an error or stacktrace? do you know the value of the resultset? did you test your query directly on the database? did that work

Comment: What do you mean by *its not working*?

Comment: actually its running fine the ist query but 2nd query result not displaying